# How can I create a pie chart using only the value of a cell, based on certain criteria?

Tags: pie-chart, looker-studio

I am trying to make a [pie chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7187587) that consists of the actual value (%) in a given cell, which will be selected by some filters.

I have a data set that consists of an employee per row, with several metrics in each column.

**Filters:**

- First filter on employee: `person_1`
- Second filter on wk_no: `01`

and I would like to return that value for metric x_5 >> so I want to have a pie-chart that is divided in a 65%-slice and also in a 35%-slice...

I have added an extra column: x_8 = 100%-x_5; but still haven't figured it out...

**Data table:**

| employee | emp_no | wk_no | x_1 | x_2 | x_3 | x_4 | x_5 | x_6 | x_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| person_1 | 51926 | 01 | 152 | 4% | 90 | 35 | 65% | 8% | 56% |
| person_2 | 53260 | 01 | 143 | 17% | 22 | 86 | 39% | 46% | 39% |
| person_3 | 55138 | 01 | 244 | 30% | 204 | 236 | 64% | 46% | 71% |
| person_4 | 56884 | 01 | 446 | 23% | 142 | 301 | 61% | 24% | 41% |
| person_5 | 52484 | 01 | 150 | 16% | 31 | 77 | 55% | 70% | 94% |

Files:
[datastudio report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f600713b-1caa-4d1d-8669-d5e4b076f1c6)
[dataset sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tjIX55ukCu5gKKW_zuRoRKRwxjb4J7PYd1V6ciMMhnI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Lighthouse Gauge chart, see Community visualizations.